# FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host when setting up blazer gem

Tags: ruby, postgresql, engineyard

My application uses the blazer gem for visualizing DB queries.

During the setup I've encountered the following error:

`FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "111.22.33.44", user "blazer", database "my_db", SSL off`

My application is hosted on EngineYard and uses PostgreSQL.

How can I find and modify the pg_hba.conf on EngineYard?

upd

I do have SSH access to EngineYard cloud.

Instance: `General Purpose (M3) Large`.

OS: EngineYard's Gentoo.

Comment: `show hba_file` in psql and vi it

Comment: What is the OS? Do you have SSH access? Dou you have sudo permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following steps. I've assumed that your DB name is `my_db`.

- Connect to the instance via SSH (the link can be found on the EngineYard environment page)
- Connect to the
  database as superuser `psql -U postgres -h localhost -d
  my_db`. If you don't have the password, check your database secrets here `/data/my_db/current/config/database.yml`
- After connecting to DB identify location of hba file by typing `SHOW
  hba_file;`
- Quit psql by typing `\q`
- Use previously identified path to open the `hba_file` file and add the missing user. E.g via vim `sudo vim /db/postgresql/9.5/data/pg_hba.conf`. Note the sudo command
- The use should be added under `# IPv4 postgres
  user for 10.x with md5:`
- Connect to the database again
- Reload the configuration via `select pg_reload_conf();` command

After all steps are performed, Blazer queries should be accessible.

Comment: I've followed the steps above but I'm still getting the same error. I'd be really gratefully if someone added a sample hba entry to the answer above. Otherwise the answer is excellent.